# Allocated memory for a matrix can't be filled for some specific values

Tags: c

So i made this program, where it crates 2 matrixes(m1**,m2**), than multiple them.
But it randomly crashes with some values (exemples: m1[2][1], m2[2][1]; 
m1[4]m2[3], in this last instance it breakes before i choocle m2 values).
I know the problem happens after allocating memory, so it might be when the matrixes are being filled (preencherMatrix funtion).
I don't know why, could you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
    int dX,dY;
    int** mat;
} MATRIX;

MATRIX criarMatrix (MATRIX mat)
{
    int aux;

    printf("MATRIX \n");
    printf("Dimensao X: \n");
    scanf("%d",&aux);
    mat.dX=aux;
    printf("Dimensao Y: \n");
    scanf("%d",&aux);
    mat.dY=(int)aux;

    int index;

    mat.mat=(int**)malloc(mat.dX*sizeof(int*));
        for (index=0;index<mat.dY;index++)
            mat.mat[index]=(int*)malloc(mat.dY*sizeof(int));

    return(mat);
}

MATRIX preencherMatrix (MATRIX mat)
{
    int x,y;

    for(x=0;x<mat.dX;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<mat.dY;y++)
        {
            mat.mat[x][y]=rand()%11;
        }
    }
    return(mat);
}

void printMatrix (MATRIX mat)
{
    int x,y;

    printf("\n................... \n");
    for(x=0;x<mat.dX;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<mat.dY;y++)
        {
            printf("%d ",mat.mat[x][y]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf("................... \n");
}

MATRIX multiplicaMatrix (MATRIX m1, MATRIX m2)
{
    int x,y,i,j;

    x=m1.dX;
    y=m2.dY;

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            m1.mat[i][j]=m1.mat[i][j]*m2.mat[j][i];
        }
    }
    return(m1);
}

void main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    MATRIX m1;
    MATRIX m2;

    m1=criarMatrix(m1);
    m1=preencherMatrix(m1);
    printMatrix(m1);

    m2=criarMatrix(m2);
    m2=preencherMatrix(m2);
    printMatrix(m2);

    if (m1.dX!=m2.dY)
    {
        printf("Numero de colunas de M1 e diferente do numero de filas de M2\n \n");
        return(-1);
    }

    m1=multiplicaMatrix(m1,m2);
    printMatrix(m1);
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the matrices by value to your functions?

Comment: In `criarMatrix`, the allocation loops aren't using `dY` and `dX` correctly. You allocate with `dX` and loop with `dY`. That code can only work if `dX` and `dY` are the same, i.e. a square matrix.

Comment: wait, how it is not correct? 
Im allocating dX, than looping dY

    mat.mat=(int**)malloc(mat.dX*sizeof(int*));
        for (index=0;index<mat.dY;index++)
            mat.mat[index]=(int*)malloc(mat.dY*sizeof(int));

Comment: For example, let's say `dX` is 3 and `dY` is 500. So the first `malloc` allocates memory for 3 pointers. And then the `for` loop goes from 0 to 499, creating 500 pointers to put in that memory.

Answer (score 1):

This line `for (index=0;index<mat.dY;index++)` after the 1st `malloc` should have `index < mat.dX`.

You have allocated the 1st dimension with `dX`, so the loop for the 2nd dimension should run from `0..dX-1`